# unable to use group by and not in to retrieve data, MySql

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hope someone can help me on this. My table looks like this:

```
user_id    query_id
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            4
2            5
4            6
```

basically for each query_id it's linked to a user.id and it can be many-to-one.

what i was looking for is all the queries except the first one that belong to their corresponding users, or:

```
user_id    query_id
1            2
1            3
2            5
```

here's my code:

```
SELECT query_id FROM query WHERE query_id NOT IN
(SELECT query_id FROM query GROUP BY user_id)
```

By using group by function I was able to select each first query that corresponding to each user ID. However when I was adding NOT IN I got an empty table. I also tried left join function but it did not help either.

I would really appreciate anyone who can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, query_id
FROM mytable 
WHERE query_id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(query_id)
                       FROM mytable
                       GROUP BY user_id)
```

The subquery will select values `(1), (4), (6)` based on the sample data provided. Hence the main query will filter out all of the records having these `query_id` values.

Comment: @sagi Yes, because OP states that it is a *many-to-one* relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT t.user_id,t.query_id
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
             WHERE s.user_id = t.user_id
               AND t.query_id > s.query_id)
```

Or:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.query_id
FROM YourTable t
WHERE (t.user_id,t.query_id) NOT IN (SELECT s.user_id,MIN(s.query_id)
                                     FROM YourTable s
                                     GROUP BY s.user_id)
```